# Drupal Form to Choose Embedded View

Tags: views, forms

I'm trying to create a form that will allow a user to select a View from a list and then display that View on the same page. For instance:

```
$options = array();
$options['view_one'] = 'view_one';
$options['view_two'] = 'view_two';
$options['view_three'] = 'view_three';

$form['chooseview']=array(
    '#title'=>'Choose a View',
    '#description'=>'Which View do you want to display?',
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#name'=>'chooseview',
    '#required'=>TRUE,
    '#options' => $options,
    );

print views_embed_view($form_state['values']['chooseview'],'block_1');
```

My question is how do I accomplish this? Drupal is not printing the embedded View from `form_submit`. I don't need Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method #1: (No subit button, requires JS, loads all views at once but shows conditionally)**

```
<?php 
function MYMODULE_my_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $options = array();
  $options['view_one'] = 'view_one';
  $options['view_two'] = 'view_two';
  $options['view_three'] = 'view_three';

  $form['chooseview']=array(
    '#title' => t('Choose a View'),
    '#description' => t('Which View do you want to display?'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#name' => 'chooseview',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $options,
  );
  foreach ($options as $view_name) {
    $form['display'][$view_name] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup', // Not necessary - just to be clear. 
      '#markup' => views_embed_view($view_name, 'block_1'),
      '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
          ':input[name="chooseview"]' => array('value' => $view_name),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  return $form;
?>
```

(short, eh)

**Method #2: (Submit button, JS-independent, loads only view when necessary)**
Note we pass `$form_state` to the form builder function by reference.

```
<?php 
function MYMODULE_my_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $options = array();
  $options['view_one'] = 'view_one';
  $options['view_two'] = 'view_two';
  $options['view_three'] = 'view_three';

  $form['chooseview']=array(
    '#title' => t('Choose a View'),
    '#description' => t('Which View do you want to display?'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#name' => 'chooseview',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $options,
  );
  $form['show_me'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Show me, please!'),
  );
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['chooseview'])) {
    $form['display'][$view_name] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup', // Not necessary - just to be clear. 
      '#markup' => views_embed_view($form_state['values']['chooseview'], 'block_1'),
    );
  }
}

function MYMODULE_my_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
?>
```